# How to bundle/nest crates when publishing?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a project in which I split into multiple crates for better organization, modules are used too however some parts of the project while logically stand-alone, are only useful in the context of my project and aren't intended to be feature-complete, general purpose libraries.

For example, I have a crate that writes a file-format, but only supports a limited feature set needed for the application.

When I tried to publish this on [crates.io](https://crates.io/), It seems necessary to publish all nested crates as well *(apologies for not having the exact error, but I rather not accidentally publish a crate just to test this again)*.

Since it doesn't make much sense to use outside this project and definitely don't make sense to be listed in the root name-space on `crates.io`.

Is it possible to publish a project on `crates.io` that includes nested creates that aren't themselves published on `crates.io`?

---

Added note, since crates may be end-user applications, see: *["Should end users utilities/applications be uploaded to crates.io?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276715)*
There are cases when crates may be a component of the application, where there isn't any intention of writing a library for others to build into their projects.

Comment: If I, for example, were to come across your crate on `crates.io` and decided to use it in my project.. what do you expect to happen when I try to build my project? If the answer is: "it should fail" - why are you putting your crate on `crates.io` in the first place? (genuinely curious.. I don't quite understand)

Comment: Good point, since this is more a utility/application - I wanted to put it on `crates.io` as a way for others to be able to install it. Possibly this is a misuse of `crates.io`, the FAQ doesn't mention this, and there are examples of end-users tools already. Will edit the question.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead, even discounting the case of applications, its possible a high-level library might include low-level crates which aren't so useful to expose on their own.

Comment: I personally think that as long as the description is clear (and you could call it myapp-mylib) there's no problem. But I'll be watching as I'm going to be in a similar position at some point!

Comment: @Chris Emerson, even in this case... I don't want anyone else to use it for practical reasons (it's open source so of course they can use if they really want), I just want to isolate code within an application and not have to consider API compatibility, updating every crate for a release of the application... and figure out what happens if the application no longer needs it. While `myapp-mylib` can work, it feels like a misuse of crates.io.

Comment: I think you should ask this on https://users.rust-lang.org/.