# Should end user utilities/applications be registered on crates.io?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

Is it acceptable to register generally useful (utilities / applications) on [crates.io](http://crates.io)?

The [FAQ](http://doc.crates.io/faq.html) doesn't address this and from browsing, there are examples of end-user applications (mostly command line tools).

Or is crates.io? meant only for libraries?

---

I'm asking this because the documentation hints at library use, semantic versioning for API's etc. but doesn't reference the case for packaging applications explicitly.

Comment: I think it's more about whether the utilities/applications will be useful to users beside yourself rather than crate type, e.g. application or libraries. A good rule of thumb is whether it's worth to put the source on GitHub.

Comment: @WiSaGaN: I put all my projects, even unfinished pet projects, on github, simply because it makes for an easy back-up :/

Comment: @MatthieuM. oops, seems not a good indicator then.

Comment: @WiSaGaN, yes, they are generally useful utilities - updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because you can use `cargo install` to install and manage those applications system-wide. If this use were discouraged, I would suspect that command to not exist at all, or at least have a very limited applicability.

Snippet from `cargo install --help`:

> Usage:
>
> ```
>  cargo install [options] [<crate>]
>  cargo install [options] --list
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> This command manages Cargo's local set of installed binary crates.
>   Only packages which have `[[bin]]` targets can be installed, and all
>   binaries are installed into the installation root's `bin` folder. The
>   installation root is determined, in order of precedence, by `--root`,
>   `$CARGO_INSTALL_ROOT`, the `install.root` configuration key, and
>   finally the home directory (which is either `$CARGO_HOME` if set or
>   `$HOME/.cargo` by default).
>
> There are multiple sources from which a crate can be installed. The
>   default location is crates.io but the `--git` and `--path` flags can
>   change this source. If the source contains more than one package (such
>   as crates.io or a git repository with multiple crates) the `<crate>`
>   argument is required to indicate which crate should be installed.

Answer (score 1):

*This should not be the primary reason to publish an application to crates.io, but I'm listing it here because it's still a good reason. :)*

The Rust team will occasionally use a tool called [crater](https://github.com/brson/taskcluster-crater) to check for regressions on all crates published on crates.io, usually before merging a pull request that has uncertain consequences. If you wrote some code that happens to compile today but would stop compiling<sup>1</sup> due to a bug fix in the compiler, then they may even submit a pull request to your project that fixes your code!

---

<sup>1</sup> Usually, when such breaking changes occur, there's at least one prior release in which a warning will be reported before the warning is turned into an error.